# Switching between fragments causes UI to block - How to load fragment using async?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

So I have an Activity with two fragments.

One of the fragments is a map fragment and whenever I load it for the first time, there is a pretty significant delay and the UI is pretty much blocked. This is how I switch/start my fragments:

```
private void showMapFragment(){
    m_VenuesMapFragment = VenuesMapFragment.getInstance(getVenuesBundle());
    actionBar.setTitle(cat.getName() + " - Map");
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

I have a loading animation in my Activity's layout whenever I switch from one fragment to another, but the loading animation simply blocks until the fragment is ready so there is really no point of showing it, unless I can animate it, which then depends on loading the fragment in a different thread.

**Question:**

Is there any way to load the fragment in a sort of async way and display a loading screen until the fragment is created without blocking the UI thread?

Answer (score 0):

use intent service to start asyncTask and register reciever in MapFragment.
That will make your Loader visible in mapfragment until service has received data.
in OnRecieve, show the data and hide Loader.
To start Service for asyncTask u may want a look at 
http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html